# Programmatically close aspx page from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to close an ASPX page from the code-behind?

I have a button event handler that I want to close the page after the user has clicked an ASP.NET button on the page.  I have tried to programmatically add a JavaScript method that contains a `window.close()` command to the `OnClientClick` event to close the page but it does not work.  The button is also a `asp:AsyncPostBoskTrigger` for an AJAX Update Panel.

The application uses .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I have taken all of your input and came up with the following solution:

In code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();");
}
```

In aspx page:

```
function CloseWindow() {
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: it makes a postback, and in the second click, IE asks confirmation to close browser.

Answer (score 55):

You would typically do something like:

```cs
protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.close();", true);
}
```

However, keep in mind that different things will happen in different scenerios.
Firefox won't let you close a window that wasn't opened by you (opened with `window.open()`).

IE7 will prompt the user with a "This page is trying to close (Yes | No)" dialog.

In any case, you should be prepared to deal with the window not always closing!

One fix for the 2 above issues is to use:

```cs
protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.open('close.html', '_self', null);", true);
}
```

And create a close.html:

```html
<html><head>
 <title></title>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var redirectTimerId = 0;
     function closeWindow()
     {
         window.opener = top;
         redirectTimerId = window.setTimeout('redirect()', 2000);
         window.close(); 
     }

     function stopRedirect()
     {
         window.clearTimeout(redirectTimerId);
     }

     function redirect()
     {
         window.location = 'default.aspx';
     }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="closeWindow()" onunload="stopRedirect()" style="">
     <center><h1>Please Wait...</h1></center>
 </body></html>
```

Note that close.html will redirect to default.aspx if the window does not close after 2 sec for some reason.

Comment: On Firefox this is the only thing I've ever found that works because you can only close a window you've opened.  In FireFox, it always redirects, so you have to find an appropriate place to take the user since you can't close the window, such as a login page or home page or leave the user on this page with an appropriate message.  I had same problem in Edge.

Answer (score 10):

```
 protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          // Your code goes here.
          if(isSuccess)
          {
                  string  close =    @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                                window.returnValue = true;
                                window.close();
                                </script>";
            base.Response.Write(close);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 7):

A postback is the process of re-loading a page, so if you want the page to close after the postback then you need to set your window.close() javascript to run with the browser's onload event during that postback, normally done using the `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` function.

But are you sure this is what you want to do?  Closing pages tends to piss off users.

Answer (score 7):

You should inject a startup script that will close the page after the postback has finished.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closePage", "<script type='text/JavaScript'>window.close();</script>");
```

Comment: It used that line of code to my page, and it closed it right away. I need to close th page once the user clicks the ASP.NET button control on the page.

Comment: Put it in the button onclick event handler in the codebehind.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add this property in your asp:Button element (for example):

```
OnClientClick="javascript:window.close();"
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

If you using RadAjaxManager then you can use this:

```
RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add("window.opener.location.href = '../CaseManagement/LCCase.aspx?" + caseId + "'; 
window.close();");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can close a window by simply pasting the window closing code in the button's OnClientClick event in the markup

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering why they cannot get the provided answers to work it's because the page must have been opened by javascript in order to be closed by javascript.

Since most people finding this asp question are likely using an `asp:hyperlink` or an asp redirect of some sort to navigate to the page that needs to be closed. These methods of redirection don't use javascript and therefore will not close by javascript.

I found a simple solution for my application and that's eliminating the `NavigateUrl` and using the `asp:Hyperlink.Attributes` to add an `onclick` to the hyperlink which uses java script to open the window that needs to be closed by javascript.

```
aspHyperlink.NavigateUrl = "https://www.google.com";
```

The above NavigateUrl is removed and instead we attach our click event.

```
aspHyperlink.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:openInNewTab('https://www.google.com');");
```

And in the code behind of the page containing our aspHyperlink we have the javascript for opening the url provided by [Rinto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
         var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
         win.focus();
     }
```

Now all pages opened with `openInNewTab` can be closed with the provided answers.

```
window.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

For closing a asp.net windows application,

- Just drag a button into the design page
- Then write the below given code inside its click event

  ```
         "   this.close();  "
  ```

ie:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {
        this.Close();
 }
```

Comment: this is not windows forms

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick"," CloseWindow();");
  }

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CloseWindow() 
      {
         window.close();
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please correct the formatting of your code. Also provide text to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use this.. short and easy.

```
Response.Write("<script>window.close();</script>");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you are opening page on JavaScript popup
then

```
 Response.Write("<script>javascript:window.close();</script>");
```

will do the job