# asp.net run function then close the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a specific requirement, which is when the user clicks on a button, I want to save some data then close the page.

I already did the saving function,

but I don't know what should I do to make the close option.

#### I mean that after saving, the page should automatically close

how can I achieve that please?

I am using asp.net with windows server 2003 on IE 8

Comment: Take a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375406/programmatically-close-aspx-page-from-code-behind)

Comment: Never close a browser page you didn't yourself open. You can redirect somewhere else, but don't close the user's browser window.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn it is a required function from my boss

Comment: @Andrei that thread helps, type an answer to accept it

Comment: I understand that sometimes you have to follow orders. But you can also push back first... unless you first opened this window yourself via javascript, closing the window creates a horrible user experience, because this can make the entire browser just go away. It will help your case if you can offer an alternative: redirect to a different page, with clearly labeled "close window" text and perhaps a small menu to other areas of your site.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I would do that but actually this is my 7th day in work. So, I don't want to upset my boss, who I have never seen bty, by something he already ordered. It would be like, "this is your first week and you start intervention in our business". I myself don't like the close too :)

Comment: @user2226785, that would be a link-only answer, which is no good

Answer (score 0):

In your button click event you can call the save data method and then at the end of the saving method put below line of code to close the page

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closePage", "<script type='text/JavaScript'>window.close();</script>");
```