# Closing aspx modal from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to close an aspx modal from code-behind using this code-

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Close_Window", "self.close();", true);
```

It works perfectly well when I use Google Chrome, but Internet Explorer fails. Any ideas why?

Thanx in advance for the assistance

Comment: Check it http://stackoverflow.com/q/375406/3835843

Comment: Any ideas how it fails? Sorry, but this post really lacks any details.

Comment: What kind of modal? There are several

Comment: self.close(); won't close a modal it'll close a page. @Andrei is right this is missing several crucial points and is conflicting..

Comment: please show you popup code , which type of popup you are using

Comment: What is an ASPX modal?

Answer (score 0):

try this for IE

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>self.close();</script>");
```

Comment: so which function close your popup , just replace on this one self.close();

Comment: if you are using Model popup then put this code    $.modal.close();